# how to return a flag value based on table data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table "emp" as like follows in BIG QUERY

[image]

If we group by all columns or distinct records then we will get 3 as count, if we count(*) then it will give 4

I need to write a query which has to return "1", if distinct records and count(*) values are not equal (3 != 4 in our case) else "0" as flag like as below

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT FORMAT('%t', t)), 0, 1) AS flag
FROM `project.dataset.emp` t
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row flag     
1   1
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find duplicates, you can use:

```
select empno, empname, deptno
from t
group by empno, empname, deptno
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can then incorporate this into a query to return a flag if you like:

```
select exists (select 1
               from t
               group by empno, empname, deptno
               having count(*) > 1
              ) as flag
```

Answer (score 0):

This might scale a little nicer ...

- just replace bigquery-public-DATA with your project and austin_bikeshare with your dataset.

Why nicer ?

1. querying __ TABLE __ is not billed so free :-)
2. Count distinct over the hash is slightly faster (would use approx_count_distinct and round if super large datasets)
3. Your flag results in a number between 0 and 1 - showing scale of dups in each table - this can be
4. Running over the whole dataset which I'm assuming you'll do is trivial.

#standard sql:

```
select 
  b.table_id Table_Name
  ,round(safe_divide(count(distinct(FARM_FINGERPRINT(FORMAT('%T', a)))) , row_count),4) dup_ratio 
  ,cast( trunc(safe_divide(count(distinct(FARM_FINGERPRINT(FORMAT('%T', a)))) , row_count)) as INT64) your_flag 
from 
  `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.*` a
inner join 
  bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.__TABLES__ b 
 on a._TABLE_SUFFIX = b.table_id
group by 
  table_id  ,row_count
```

Result :

```
Table_Name           dup_ratio  your_flag
bikeshare_stations   0.0104     0
bikeshare_trips      1.0        1
```